# What is the relation between Quasicrystals, Riemann Hypothesis, and PV numbers?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

Could somebody explain to me, from a mathematical stand-point, what is a quasi-crystal, and how it relates to the set of Pisot numbers, and the Riemann Hypothesis?

I've heard Freeman Dyson say that the zeros of the Riemann zeta function form a quasi-crystal. But, a priori, I do not see what kind of property of the zeros, that we currently now of, would be able to confer to them more structure than to a random set of isolated numbers.

(Notwithstanding the explicit formula in prime number theory)

To wit, my second question possibly based on a misunderstanding: why is the set of zeros of $\zeta(s)$ a quasi-crystal, while a random sequence of isolated numbers is not? Of course, I first need to fully understand what is a quasi-crystal, because Freeman's definition left me in a fog.

Comment: Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: What makes you think Pisot numbers relate to quasi-crystals and/or the Riemann Hypothesis? Did Dyson say something about those, too?

Comment: Dyson said that every PV number gives rise to a quasi crystal. Anyway, do you know of a solid definition of quasi crystal? I do not believe there is a relation between PV numbers and RH.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasicrystal. Please try Wikipedia before posting here.

Comment: Dyson's definition of a quasicrystal is not equivalent to the one in Wikipedia. 

Comment: Indeed, but the article says there is more than one definition. Which implies that the concept is used somewhat like "fractal": in a science text it may mean something but what it means may not be a piece of mathematics. 

Comment: @Charles: The author of wikipedia article is not a mathematician, so he/she does not understand the difference between the words "define" and "construct."  

Comment: Dyson's thing had something to do with something being its own Fourier transform makes that something a quasicrystal http://www.ams.org/notices/200902/rtx090200212p.pdf

Answer (score 20):

[Freeman Dyson's proposal](https://www.msri.org/publications/ln/msri/2002/rmt/dyson/1/meta/aux/dyson.pdf) is online, based on [a talk he gave at MSRI](https://archive.org/details/lecture_10000).

Lillian Pierce's [senior thesis](https://services.math.duke.edu/~pierce/theses/Pierce_Senior_Thesis.pdf) gives a summary of Peter Sarnak's program to use properties of Gaussian Unitary Ensemble to study the zeros of the Riemann Zeta function.

N. G. Debrujin wrote about [Penrose tilings](https://alexandria.tue.nl/repository/freearticles/597566.pdf) and their [Fourier transforms](https://alexandria.tue.nl/repository/freearticles/597578.pdf).

---

Crystalline structures on the line are pretty boring.   They are just evenly spaced lattices, like $\mathbb{Z}$, which might appear on different scales.

```
--o---o---o---o---o---o---o--
---o-----o-----o-----o-----o-
```

However, there are many quasi-periodic structures on the line, for example $\lfloor n\sqrt{2}\rfloor
= \{ 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14,\dots  \}$ which we can draw on the line.

```
--o--o-----o--o-----o--o--o-----o--o-----o--
```

Many of these have special recursive properties.  Consider the line $y = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} x$ which Golden ration slope.  Mark "0" if it crosses a horizontal line and "1" if for a vertical line.  You get the Fibonacci Word
[image]
Of course in 2D you get more interesting quasicrystals, which have interesting number theoretic and recursive structures.
[image]
Freeman Dyson wishes the zeros of the Riemann Hypotheses have structure like these.

Comment: @John: What your definition of quasi-periodicity? As far as I understand the question, one issue is lack of precise definitions in the quasicrystal literature, which is dominated by physics papers. 
Also, your 2nd link is broken. 

Comment: See the newer question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/133581/quasicrystals-and-the-riemann-hypothesis

