# Is this similarity to the Fourier transform of the von Mangoldt function real?

Tags: nt.number-theory, fourier-analysis

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/424530/248451) question proposed in SEM but no answer and it's interesting to know connection

between  Fourier analysis and number theory .

Mathematica knows that the logarithm of $n$ is:

$$\log(n) = \lim\limits_{s \rightarrow 1} \zeta(s)\left(1 - \frac{1}{n^{(s - 1)}}\right)$$

The von Mangoldt function should then be:

$$\Lambda(n)=\lim\limits_{s \rightarrow 1} \zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(s-1)}}.$$

Setting the first term of the von Mangoldt function $\Lambda(1)$ equal to the harmonic number $H_{\operatorname{scale}}$ where scale is equal to the scale of the Fourier transform matrix, one can calculate the Fourier transform of the von Mangoldt function with the Mathematica program at the link below:

http://pastebin.com/ZNNYZ4F6

In the program I studied the function within the limit for the von Mangoldt function, and made some small changes to the function itself:

$f(t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=k} \frac{1}{\log(k)} \frac{1}{n} \zeta(1/2+i \cdot t)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(1/2+i \cdot t-1)}}$
as $k$ goes to infinity.

(Edit 20.9.2013: The function $f(t)$ had "-1" in the argument for the zeta function.)

The plot of this function looks like this:

[image: function]

While the plot of the Fourier transform of the von Mangoldt function with the program looks like this:

[image: Fourier transform]

There are some similarities but the Fourier transform converges faster towards smaller oscillations in between the spikes at zeta zeros and the scale factor is wrong.

Will the function $f(t)$ above eventually converge to the Fourier transform of the von Mangoldt function, or is it only yet another meaningless plot?

Now when I look at it I think the spikes at zeros comes from the zeta function itself and the spectrum like feature comes from the Möbius function which inverts the zeta function.

```
scale = 50; (*scale = 5000 gives the plot below*)
Print["Counting to 60"]
Monitor[g1 = 
  ListLinePlot[
   Table[Re[
     Zeta[1/2 + I*k]*
      Total[Table[
        Total[MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]/Divisors[n]^(1/2 + I*k - 1)]/(n*
           k), {n, 1, scale}]]], {k, 0 + 1/1000, 60, N[1/6]}], 
   DataRange -> {0, 60}, PlotRange -> {-0.15, 1.5}], Floor[k]]
```

Dirichlet series:

[image: zeta zero spectrum 1]

---

```
Clear[f]
scale = 100000;
f = ConstantArray[0, scale];
f[[1]] = N@HarmonicNumber[scale];
Monitor[Do[
  f[[i]] = N@MangoldtLambda[i] + f[[i - 1]], {i, 2, scale}], i]
xres = .002;
xlist = Exp[Range[0, Log[scale], xres]];
tmax = 60;
tres = .015;
Monitor[errList = 
   Table[(xlist^(1/2 + I k - 1).(f[[Floor[xlist]]] - xlist)), {k, 
     Range[0, 60, tres]}];, k]
ListLinePlot[Im[errList]/Length[xlist], DataRange -> {0, 60}, 
 PlotRange -> {-.01, .15}]
```

Fourier transform:

[image: zeta zero spectrum 2]

---

Matrix inverse:

```
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn]
nn = 50;
A = Table[
   Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1), 0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1,
     nn}];
MatrixForm[A];
ListLinePlot[
 Table[Total[
   1/Table[n*t, {n, 1, nn}]*
    Total[Transpose[Re[Inverse[A]*Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]]]], {t, 1/1000, 60,
    N[1/6]}], DataRange -> {0, 60}, PlotRange -> {-0.15, 1.5}]
```

---

```
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn]
nnn = 12;
Show[Flatten[{Table[
    ListLinePlot[
     Table[Re[
       Total[1/Table[n*t, {n, 1, nn}]*
         Total[Transpose[
           Inverse[
             Table[Table[
               If[Mod[n, k] == 0, N[1/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1)], 0], {k, 
                1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}]]*Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]]]], {t, 1/1000,
        60, N[1/10]}], DataRange -> {0, 60}, 
     PlotRange -> {-0.15, 1.5}], {nn, 1, nnn}], 
   Table[ListLinePlot[
     Table[Re[
       Total[1/Table[n*t, {n, 1, nn}]*
         Total[Transpose[
           Inverse[
             Table[Table[
               If[Mod[n, k] == 0, N[1/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1)], 0], {k, 
                1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}]]*Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]]]], {t, 1/1000,
        60, N[1/10]}], DataRange -> {0, 60}, 
     PlotRange -> {-0.15, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> Red], {nn, nnn, nnn}]}]]
```

12 first curves together or partial sums:

[image: 12 curves]

```
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn, dd]
dd = 220;
Print["Counting to ", dd]
nn = 20;
A = Table[
   Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1), 0], {k, 1, 
     nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
Monitor[g1 = 
   ListLinePlot[
    Table[Total[
      1/Table[n*t, {n, 1, nn}]*
       Total[Transpose[
         Re[Inverse[
           IdentityMatrix[nn] + (Inverse[A] - IdentityMatrix[nn])*
             Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]]]]], {t, 1/1000, dd, N[1/100]}], 
    DataRange -> {0, dd}, PlotRange -> {-7, 7}];, Floor[t]]
mm = N[2*Pi/Log[2], 20]
g2 = Graphics[
   Table[Style[Text[n, {mm*n, 1}], FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
     FontSize -> 14], {n, 1, 32}]];
Show[g1, g2, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Matrix Inverse of matrix inverse times zeta function (on critical line):

[image: matrix inverse of matrix inverse as function of t]

```
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn, h]
nn = 60;
h = 2; (*h=2 gives log 2 operator, h=3 gives log 3 operator and so on*)
A = Table[
   Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 
     If[Mod[n/k, h] == 0, 1 - h, 1]/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1), 0], {k, 1, 
     nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
MatrixForm[A];
g1 = ListLinePlot[
   Table[Total[
     1/Table[n*t, {n, 1, nn}]*
      Total[Transpose[Re[Inverse[A]*Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]]]], {t, 1/1000, 
     nn, N[1/6]}], DataRange -> {0, nn}, PlotRange -> {-3, 7}];
mm = N[2*Pi/Log[h], 12]
g2 = Graphics[
   Table[Style[Text[n*2*Pi/Log[h], {mm*n, 1}], 
     FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 14], {n, 1, 32}]];
Show[g1, g2, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Matrix inverse of Riemann zeta times log 2 operator:

[image: 2 Pi div log2 spectrum]

[Jeffrey Stopple's code](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~stopple/zeta.html):

```
Show[Graphics[
  RasterArray[
   Table[Hue[
     Mod[3 Pi/2 + Arg[Zeta[sigma + I t]], 2 Pi]/(2 Pi)], {t, -30, 
     30, .1}, {sigma, -30, 30, .1}]]], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Normal or usual zeta:

[image: Normal zeta]

```
Show[Graphics[
  RasterArray[
   Table[Hue[
     Mod[3 Pi/2 + 
        Arg[Sum[Zeta[sigma + I t]*
           Total[1/Divisors[n]^(sigma + I t - 1)*
              MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]]/n, {n, 1, 30}]], 
       2 Pi]/(2 Pi)], {t, -30, 30, .1}, {sigma, -30, 30, .1}]]], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Spectral zeta (30-th partial sum):

[image: spectral zeta]

```
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn, B]
nn = 60
A = Table[
  Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1), 0], {k, 1, 
    nn}], {n, 1, nn}]; MatrixForm[A];
B = FourierDCT[
   Table[Total[
     1/Table[n, {n, 1, nn}]*
      Total[Transpose[Re[Inverse[A]*Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]]]], {t, 1/1000, 
     600, N[1/6]}]];
g1 = ListLinePlot[B[[1 ;; 700]]*Table[Sqrt[n], {n, 1, 700}], 
   DataRange -> {0, 60}, PlotRange -> {-60, 600}];
mm = 11.35/Log[2];
g2 = Graphics[
   Table[Style[Text[n, {mm*Log[n], 100 + 20*(-1)^n}], 
     FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 14], {n, 1, 16}]];
Show[g1, g2, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Mobius function -> Dirichlet series -> Spectral Riemann zeta -> Fourier transform -> von Mangoldt function:

[image: from Mobius via spectral Riemann zeta to von Mangoldt]

Larger von Mangoldt function plot still wrong amplitude:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/02A1p.jpg

```
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn, B, g1, g2]
nn = 32
A = Table[
   Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1), 0], {k, 1, 
     nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
MatrixForm[A];
B = FourierDCT[
   Table[Total[
     1/Table[n, {n, 1, nn}]*
      Total[Transpose[Re[Inverse[A]*Zeta[1/2 + I*t]]]]], {t, 0, 2000, 
     N[1/6]}]];
g1 = ListLinePlot[B[[1 ;; 2000]], DataRange -> {0, 60}, 
   PlotRange -> {-5, 50}];
2*N[Length[B]/1500, 12]
mm = 13.25/Log[2];
g2 = Graphics[
   Table[Style[Text[n, {mm*Log[n], 7 + (-1)^n}], 
     FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 14], {n, 1, 40}]];
Show[g1, g2, ImageSize -> Full]
```

Plot from program above: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6mTJ.jpg

Partial sums of zeta function, use this one:

```
Clear[n, k, t, A, nn, B]
nn = 80
mm = 11.35/Log[2];
A = Table[
   Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1/(n/k)^(1/2 + I*t - 1), 0], {k, 1, 
     nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
MatrixForm[A];
B = Re[FourierDCT[
    Monitor[Table[
      Total[1/Table[
          n, {n, 1, nn}]*(Total[
           Transpose[Inverse[A]*Sum[1/j^(1/2 + I*t), {j, 1, nn}]]] - 
          1)], {t, 1/1000, 600, N[1/6]}], Floor[t]]]];
g1 = ListLinePlot[B[[1 ;; 700]], DataRange -> {0, 60/mm}, 
   PlotRange -> {-30, 30}];
g2 = Graphics[
   Table[Style[Text[n, {Log[n], 5 - (-1)^n}], 
     FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 14], {n, 1, 32}]];
Show[g1, g2, ImageSize -> Full]
```

---

Edit 17.1.2015:

```
Clear[g1, g2, scale, xres, x, a, c, d, datapointsdisplayed]
scale = 1000000;
xres = .00001;
x = Exp[Range[0, Log[scale], xres]];
a = -FourierDCT[
    Log[x]*FourierDST[
      MangoldtLambda[Floor[x]]*(SawtoothWave[x] - 1)*(x)^(-1/2)]];
c = 62.357
d = N[Im[ZetaZero[1]]]
datapointsdisplayed = 500000;
ymin = -1.5;
ymax = 3;
p = 0.013;
g1 = ListLinePlot[a[[1 ;; datapointsdisplayed]], 
   PlotRange -> {ymin, ymax}, 
   DataRange -> {0, N[Im[ZetaZero[1]]]/c*datapointsdisplayed}];
Show[g1, Graphics[
  Table[Style[Text[n, {22800*Log[n], -1/4*(-1)^n}], 
    FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 14], {n, 1, 12}]], 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: MangoldLambdaTautology]

```
Show[Graphics[
  RasterArray[
   Table[Hue[
     Mod[3 Pi/2 + 
        Arg[Sum[Zeta[sigma - I t]*
           Total[1/Divisors[n]^(sigma + I t)*MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]]/
            n, {n, 1, 30}]], 2 Pi]/(2 Pi)], {t, -30, 
     30, .1}, {sigma, -30, 30, .1}]]], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: spectral riemann]

Comment: This has been asked here before, it looks like this is simply a copy of such post.

Comment: @ok, thank you very much peter, could you give me link ?

Comment: @Peter, I think in this :http://mathoverflow.net/q/162076/75050 , sorry i didn't get attention