# Does it make sense to express upper bounds on arithmetic sequences with Dirichlet generating functions?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, asymptotics, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis, gamma-function

In order to see what happens when taking the functional equation in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/7656/25104) form:
$$\xi(s) := \pi^{-s/2}\ \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\ \zeta(s) $$
$$\xi(s) = \xi(1 - s)$$
$$\pi^{-s/2}\ \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\ \zeta(s)=\pi^{-(1-s)/2}\ \Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)\ \zeta(1-s)\tag{$\ast$}$$

and applying it to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/162076/25104) Dirichlet generating function (in two variables):

$$\frac{\zeta(s)\ \zeta(c)}{\zeta(s+c-1)}\tag{$\ast \ast$}$$

associated with the GCD matrix that has the property stated more clearly by GH from MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/308990/25104):

$$\Lambda(m)=\lim_{s\to 1+}\zeta(s)\sum_{d\mid m}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^{s-1}}=\lim_{s\to 1+}\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}\left(\sum_{d\mid\gcd(n,m)}d\mu(d)\right),\qquad m>1.$$

Applying $(\ast)$ to $( \ast \ast )$ we get:

$$\frac{\pi^{-s/2}\ \pi^{-c/2}}{\pi^{-s/2-c/2+1/2}}\ \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{c}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}+\frac{c}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\ \frac{\zeta(s)\ \zeta(c)}{\zeta(s+c-1)}=\frac{\pi^{-(1-s)/2}\ \pi^{-(1-c)/2}}{\pi^{-((1-s)+(1-c)-(1-1))/2}}\ \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)\ \Gamma\left(\frac{1-c}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}+\frac{1-c}{2}-\frac{1-1}{2}\right)}\ \frac{\zeta(1-s)\ \zeta(1-c)}{\zeta((1-s)+(1-c)-(1-1))}$$

Moving the Riemann zeta functions to the left hand side, we get:

$$\frac{\zeta(s)\ \zeta(c)}{\zeta(s+c-1)}\ \frac{\zeta((1-s)+(1-c)-(1-1))}{\zeta(1-s)\ \zeta(1-c)}=\frac{\pi^{-(1-s)/2}\ \pi^{-(1-c)/2}}{\pi^{-((1-s)+(1-c)-(1-1))/2}}\frac{\pi^{-s/2-c/2+1/2}}{\pi^{-s/2}\ \pi^{-c/2}}\ \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)\ \Gamma\left(\frac{1-c}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}+\frac{1-c}{2}-\frac{1-1}{2}\right)}\ \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}+\frac{c}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{c}{2}\right)} \tag{$\ast \ast \ast$}$$

If replace the variable $s$ in:
$$\frac{\zeta(s)\ \zeta(c)}{\zeta(s+c-1)}\ \frac{\zeta((1-s)+(1-c)-(1-1))}{\zeta(1-s)\ \zeta(1-c)}$$
with $s=\frac{1}{2}+it$, and let $c=1+\frac{1}{2}$, so that we get:

$$\frac{\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)\ \zeta(1+\frac{1}{2})}{\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it+1+\frac{1}{2}-1)}\ \frac{\zeta((1-(\frac{1}{2}+it))+(1-(1+\frac{1}{2}))-(1-1))}{\zeta(1-(\frac{1}{2}+it))\ \zeta(1-(1+\frac{1}{2}))}$$

Plotting the negated real part:

$$-\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\Re\left(\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right) \zeta (-i t)}{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}-i t\right) \zeta (1+i t)}\right) \approx \sqrt{8 \pi  t}$$

we observe that the function is close to $\sqrt{8 \pi  t}$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

The constant: $-\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}=$[N[-Zeta[3/2]/Zeta[-1/2], 40]](https://oeis.org/search?q=12.566370614359172953850&sort=&language=swedish&go=S%C3%B6k)=12.56637061435917295385...
has something to do with quasicrystals according the OEIS.

Mathematica:

```
Plot[-Re[(Zeta[3/2]*Zeta[1/2 + I*t]*Zeta[(-I)*t])/(Zeta[-(1/2)]*
  Zeta[1/2 - I*t]*Zeta[1 + I*t])], {t, 0, 60}]

Plot[Sqrt[8*Pi*t], {t, 0, 60}]
```

[Plot in Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B-Re%5B%28Zeta%5B3%2F2%5D*Zeta%5B1%2F2+%2B+I*t%5D*Zeta%5B%28-I%29*t%5D%29%2F%28Zeta%5B-%281%2F2%29%5D*Zeta%5B1%2F2+-+I*t%5D*Zeta%5B1+%2B+I*t%5D%29%5D%2C+%7Bt%2C+0%2C+60%7D%5D+vs+Plot%5BSqrt%5B8*Pi*t%5D%2C+%7Bt%2C+0%2C+60%7D%5D)

The proof of this asymptotic should follow somehow from asymptotic properties of the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the functional equation, which we started with.

> What I am more interested in is the overall approach. Is it worth
> expressing the [Lowell
> Schoenfeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowell_Schoenfeld) upper
> bound:
>
> $|\psi(x)-x|\le\frac{\sqrt x\,\ln^2 x}{8\pi}$
>
> in this way to make progress on the RH? Or is there some obvious drawback? The philosophy is similar to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/359060/25104), where the goal was to use the expansion of the Chebyshev psi function in order to relate it to square roots.

Notice that the logarithm part is:
$$\Re\left(\frac{\zeta '\left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)}{\zeta \left(i t+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right)^2 \approx \left(\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{t}{2 \pi }\right)\right)^2$$

by series expansion of the derivative of Riemann Siegel Theta function. And:

$$\lim_{c\to 1} \, \left(\frac{\zeta (c) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (c+s-1)}-\zeta (c)\right)=-\frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)}$$

Plot of:

$$f(t)=-\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\Re\left(\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right) \zeta (-i t)}{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}-i t\right) \zeta (1+i t)}\right)\Re\left(\frac{\zeta '\left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)}{\zeta \left(i t+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right)^2$$

Or which is the same:

$$f(t)=-\Re\left(\frac{\left(\zeta (c) \zeta \left(i t+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) \zeta \left(-c-\left(i t+\frac{1}{2}\right)+2\right)}{\zeta \left(c+\left(i t+\frac{1}{2}\right)-1\right) \left(\zeta (1-c) \zeta \left(1-\left(i t+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\right)}\right) \Re\left(\frac{\zeta '\left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)}{\zeta \left(i t+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right)^2$$

[image: Dirichlet generating function]

Plot of:

$$g(t)=\sqrt{8 \pi  t} \left(\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{t}{2 \pi }\right)\right)^2$$

[image: Square root times logarithm squared]

Curves $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ plotted together:

[image: plots together]

And the comparison of $g(t)$ with $\sqrt{t} \log ^2(t)$:
$$\lim_{t\to \infty } \, \frac{\sqrt{8 \pi  t} \left(\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{t}{2 \pi }\right)\right)^2}{\sqrt{t} \log ^2(t)} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}$$

```
Clear[s, c, t, r, q];
c = 1 + 1/2;
r = 1 + 1/1000;
ListPlot[Table[-Re[(Zeta[(1/2 + I*t)] Zeta[c] )/
      Zeta[-1 + c + (1/2 + I*t)]  * 
      Zeta[2 - c - (1/2 + I*t)]/(Zeta[1 - (1/2 + I*t)]*Zeta[1 - c])]*
   Re[Zeta'[(1/2 + I*t)] /Zeta[(1/2 + I*t)]  ]^2, {t, 0, 60, 1}], 
 DataRange -> {0, 60}]
Plot[Sqrt[8*Pi*t]*(1/2 Log[t/(2 \[Pi])])^2, {t, 0, 60}]
Show[%%, %]
ListLinePlot[
 Table[-Re[(Zeta[(1/2 + I*t)] Zeta[c] )/Zeta[-1 + c + (1/2 + I*t)]  * 
       Zeta[2 - c - (1/2 + I*t)]/(Zeta[1 - (1/2 + I*t)] Zeta[1 - c])]*
    Re[Zeta'[(1/2 + I*t)] /Zeta[(1/2 + I*t)]  ]^2 - 
   Sqrt[8*Pi*t]*(1/2 Log[t/(2 \[Pi])])^2, {t, 1/100, 60}]]
Clear[t];
Limit[(Sqrt[8*Pi*t]*(1/2 Log[t/(2 \[Pi])])^2)/(Sqrt[t]*Log[t]^2), 
 t -> Infinity]
```

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence related to your question?

Comment: @StevenClark I don't know, I can't say.

Comment: The article seems to relate the growth of the arithmetic summatory function $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a(n)$ to the abscissa of convergence of the related Dirichlet series $F(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$, so it seemed to me it's related to the title of your question, but I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: The bound on Chebyshev psi $|\psi(x)-x|$ is: $$\frac{\sqrt x\,\ln^2 x}{8\pi} \sim \sqrt{8 \pi  t} \left(\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{t}{2 \pi }\right)\right)^2 \sim -\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\Re\left(\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right) \zeta (-i t)}{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}-i t\right) \zeta (1+i t)}\right)\Re\left(\frac{\zeta '\left(\frac{1}{2}+i t\right)}{\zeta \left(i t+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right)^2$$ with the right hand side  expression consisting of Dirichlet generating functions for some two dimensional matrix yet to be explored.

Comment: Chebyshev psi is this known two dimensional matrix https://oeis.org/A309229 by the formula:    
Chebyshev psi(n) = log(A003418(n)) = Sum_{k>=1} (T(n, k)/k - 1/k). Where T(n, k)=A309229(n,k). Therefore I am seeking to compare those two matrices. The known one, and the yet to be explored one.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the two parts of your question separated by your actual question in the middle. Is the second part after your question a continuation of the first part before your question? Are either or both of these specifically related to $|\psi(x)-x|$, or are they related to the error term for some other $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a(n)$? If neither, how is the function in your question analogous to $|\psi(x)-x$|?

Comment: There are missing words in the first part, but I don't want to bump the question to the main. The second part is just some notes and observations. The function comes from: $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{T(n,k)}{n^c \cdot k^s} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lim\limits_{z \rightarrow s} \zeta(z)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(z-1)}}}{n^c} = \frac{\zeta(s) \cdot \zeta(c)}{\zeta(c + s - 1)}$$

$$-\frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)}=\lim_{c\to 1} \, \left(\frac{\zeta (c) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (c+s-1)}-\zeta (c)\right)$$
where: T(n,k) = A191898(n,k), and $s>1$ $c>1$.

Comment: The Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to is $$|\psi(x)-x|\le\frac{\sqrt x\,\ln^2 x}{8\pi}$$ for sufficiently large $x$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowell_Schoenfeld#Contributions
And A309229(n,k) is the partial column sums of A191898(n,k). But I don't know the Dirichlet generating function for A309229(n,k), other than for the row sums.