# Attempt at applying linear programming to the partial sums of the Möbius inverse of the Harmonic numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, linear-programming, riemann-hypothesis

Let $a(n)$ be the Dirichlet inverse of the Euler totient function:

$$a(n) = \sum\limits_{d|n} d \cdot \mu(d) \tag{1}$$

and let the matrix $T(n,k)$ be:
$$T(n,k)=a(\gcd(n,k)) \tag{2}$$

It has been proven by both [joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/51708/8530) and [GH from MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/162214/25104) that
for $n>1$:
$$\Lambda(n) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{T(n,k)}{k} \tag{3}$$

Let $M(n,k)$ be the lower triangular matrix:

$$M(n,k)=\underset{m\geq k}{\sum _{m=1}^n} a(\gcd (m,k)) \tag{4}$$

**Conjecture 1:** For $1 < k \leq n$, for all $n$:
$$\;\;\;\;-(k-1) \leq M(n,k) \leq (k-1)$$
**Conjecture 2:**
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{k=n} M(n,k) = 1$$

$$\sum _{k=2}^n \frac{M(n,k)}{k}=\sum _{m=1}^n \left(\underset{k \mid m}{\sum _{k=1}^m} H_k \mu \left(\frac{m}{k}\right)-1\right) \tag{5}$$

I am interested in investigating:

$$\sum _{k=2}^x \frac{M(x,k)}{k} < C\left\lfloor x^{1/2+\epsilon}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor \tag{6}$$

Therefore we form the linear programming problem $(7)$:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{k=n} \frac{y_{k}}{k} \\ \text{subject to constraints:} & n + \displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{k=n}y_{k}=1 \\ & y_1 \geq -1 \\ \text{and for $k>1$:} & M(n,k) \leq y_k \leq M(n,k) & \tag{7} \end{array}$$
The solution to the linear programming problem $(7)$ (blue dots) will automatically coincide with LHS of $(6)$ (the red lines) as shown in this graph:

[image: Linear Programming M(n,k) and M(n,k) as variable bounds]

Because of the answer to this question [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/678/671) [proven](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/681/671) by Marcus Ritt and the other parallell answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3271124/8530) by Maxim, I find it natural to ask whether the output (the blue lines) from the following linear programming problem $(8)$ is greater than $(7)$. In the program I made the change that I put the upper variable bound to $0$ and the lower variable bound to the negated absolute value of the entries in the lower triangular matrix $M(n,k)$.

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{k=n} \frac{y_{k}}{k} \\ \text{subject to constraints:} & n + \displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{k=n}y_{k}=1 \\ & y_1 \geq -1 \\ \text{and for $k>1$:} & -|M(n,k)| \leq y_k \leq 0 & \tag{8} \end{array}$$

> Can anything be said whether there exist a constant $C$ such that:
> $C$ times the output from LP-problem $(8)$ $\geq$ The output from LP-problem $(7)$?
>
> Or put in pictures. Is there a constant $C$ such that the irregular red curve is bounded by the irregular blue curve? That for $C$, however large, say $C=1000$ or greater.

What we do know given **conjecture 1** above which implies that $-|M(n,k)| \geq -(k-1)$, is that the wiggly blue curve below is bounded by the smooth continuous blue curve $f(x)$:

[image: All 3 curves together]

From the answer at the operations research forum we also know that the solutions to the linear programming problem:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{k=n} \frac{y_{k}}{k} \\ \text{subject to constraints:} & n + \displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{k=n}y_{k}=1 \\ & y_1 \geq -1 \\ \text{and for $k>1$:} & -(k-1) \leq y_k \leq 0 & \tag{9} \end{array}$$

is the continuous blue curve $f(x)$ and it is asymptotic to:

$$f(x)=C\left(-\left\lfloor \sqrt{2 (x-1)}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor +H_{\left\lfloor \sqrt{2 (x-1)}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor } + \text{Binomial term} \right) \tag{10}$$

($C=2$ was multiplied with later). Anyways, the the solutions to $(8)$ are always bounded by the solutions to $(9)$. The question is whether the solutions to $(7)$ are bounded by the solutions to $(8)$?

The binomial term can be found in the OEIS.

Edit: Minor error: $f(x)$ should have been $f(n)$ to suit the linear programming problem.

The answer, if it is to be found, lies in comparing this matrix from the solution of the Linear Programming tagged $(8)$ starting:

$$\begin{array}{llllllllllllllllll}
 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & -2 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & -2 & -1 & -1 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -2 & -3 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -2 & -2 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 & 0 & -2 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -4 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & -5 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & -2 & -1 & -2 & -2 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & -3 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -5 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -2 & -6 & -1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & -4 & 0 & -5 & 0 & -2 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -3 & -1 & -4 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 & 0 & -7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & -2 & -1 & -1 & -2 & -2 & -1 & -2 & -1 & -3 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}$$

with the matrix from the solution of the Linear Programming tagged $(7)$ which essentially is the matrix $M$ except for the first column, starting:
$$\begin{array}{llllllllllllllllll}
 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & -2 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & -2 & -1 & -3 & 2 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -2 & 3 & -6 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 2 & -5 & -1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 & 0 & -2 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -4 & -1 & -3 & -1 & -1 & 4 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 5 & -10 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & -2 & -1 & -2 & 2 & -1 & -1 & -2 & 4 & -9 & 2 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 5 & -8 & 3 & -12 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 2 & -6 & -1 & 0 & 4 & -7 & 2 & -11 & 6 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & -4 & 0 & -5 & 0 & -2 & 0 & -6 & 0 & -10 & 7 & 8 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -3 & -1 & -4 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -5 & -1 & -9 & 6 & 9 & -1 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 & 0 & -8 & 7 & 10 & 0 & -16 & \text{} \\
 1 & -1 & -2 & -1 & -1 & 2 & -2 & -1 & -2 & -1 & -3 & 2 & -7 & 6 & 8 & -1 & -15 & 2
\end{array}$$

Associated Mathematica program:
https://pastebin.com/rHaXxVcj

---

Edit: 25.11.2019:

I am not entirely sure but I believe the question approximately boils down to:

Let: $a(n)=\sum\limits_{d \mid n} \mu(d)d$

Prove or disprove that there exists a constant $c$ such that the inequality:
$$\sum\limits_{r=2}^{n} \frac{\sum\limits_{m=r}^{n} a(\gcd (m,r))}{r} \geq c\underset{\sum\limits_{k=2}^{r} -\left|\sum\limits_{m=k}^{n} a(\gcd (m,k))\right|\geq -(n-1)}{\sum _{r=2}^n} -\frac{\left|\sum\limits_{m=r}^{n} a(\gcd (m,r))\right|}{r} \tag{11}$$

holds for all $n$

I am asking because it has been [proven](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/681/671) that the right hand side is bounded from below by:

$$c\left(-\left\lfloor \sqrt{2 (n-1)}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor +H_{\left\lfloor \sqrt{2 (n-1)}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor } + \text{Binomial term} \right)$$

Mathematica:

```
Clear[a, b, nn];
nn = 60;
a[n_] := Total[MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]*Divisors[n]];
Monitor[a1 = 
   Table[Sum[Sum[a[GCD[m, r]], {m, r, n}]/r, {r, 2, n}], {n, 1, 
     nn}];, n]
g1 = ListLinePlot[a1, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
Monitor[a2 = 
   Table[Sum[
     If[Sum[-Abs[Sum[a[GCD[m, k]], {m, k, n}]], {k, 2, 
         r}] >= -(n - 1), -Abs[Sum[a[GCD[m, r]], {m, r, n}]]/r, 
      0], {r, 2, n}], {n, 1, nn}];, n]
g2 = ListLinePlot[a2, PlotStyle -> {Thick}];
Show[g2, g1]
```

[image: blue curve times constant is conjecctured to be greater than red curve]

It is as said conjectured that the blue curve times a constant is greater than the red curve. The blue curve is bounded from below by a function whose leading term is the floor function of a square root.

Same graph as above but for a 1000 times 1000 sized matrix:

[image: Partial sums of Möbius inverse of Harmonic numbers vs Square root bounded sequence]

[image: motivation for linear programming problem]

Edit 30.4.2020:
More efficient program and plot:

```
(*start*)
(*Mathematica*)
Clear[a];
nn = 2000;
constant = 2*Sqrt[2];
a[n_] := Total[Divisors[n]*MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]];
Monitor[TableForm[
   A = Accumulate[
     Table[Table[If[n >= k, a[GCD[n, k]], 0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, 
       nn}]]];, n]
TableForm[AB = Transpose[A]/Range[nn]];
AB[[1, All]] = 0;
g1 = ListLinePlot[Abs[Total[AB]], PlotStyle -> Red];
Clear[AB];
TableForm[B = -Abs[A]];
Clear[A];
B[[All, 1]] = Range[nn];
TableForm[B1 = Sign[Transpose[Accumulate[Transpose[B]]]]];
Clear[B]
Quiet[Show[
  ListLinePlot[
   v = ReplaceAll[
     Flatten[Table[First[Position[B1[[n]], -1]], {n, 1, nn}]], 
     First[{}] -> 1], PlotStyle -> Blue],
  Plot[constant*Sqrt[n], {n, 1, nn}, PlotStyle -> {Pink, Thick}], g1, 
  ImageSize -> Large]]
ListLinePlot[v/(constant*Sqrt[Range[nn]])];
(*end*)
```

The pink curve is 2*Sqrt(2)*Sqrt(x):

[image: 10000 times 10000 matrix]

Answer (score 7):

Here is a proof of Conjecture 2.

First, we have
\begin{split}
\sum_{k=1}^n M(n,k) &= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{m=k}^n \sum_{d|\gcd(m,k)} d\cdot\mu(d) \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{d|\gcd(m,k)} d\cdot\mu(d).
\end{split}

Second, denoting $g:=\gcd(m,k)$ and $k':=\frac{k}{g}$, we get:
\begin{split}
\ldots &= \sum_{m=1}^n \sum_{g|m} \sum_{k'=1\atop \gcd(k',m/g)=1}^{m/g} \sum_{d|g} d\cdot\mu(d) \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^n \sum_{g|m} \sum_{d|g} d\cdot\mu(d)\cdot\varphi(\frac{m}{g}),
\end{split}
where $\varphi(\cdot)$ is Euler's totient function.

Introducing $g':=\frac{g}{d}$ and recalling [formula (15)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html), we finally get:
\begin{split}
\ldots &= \sum_{m=1}^n \sum_{d|m} \sum_{g'|m/d} d\cdot\mu(d)\cdot\varphi(\frac{m}{g'd}) \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^n \sum_{d|m} d\cdot\mu(d)\cdot\frac{m}{d} \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^n m \sum_{d|m} \mu(d) \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^n m\cdot \delta_{m,1} \\
&= 1.
\end{split}