# The Möbius function as eigenvalues

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, mobius-inversion

Let the $N$ by $N$ matrix $A$ be defined by the tetration:

$$\Large \text{If } \gcd(n, k)=1 \text{ then } A(n,k)= \underbrace{e^{e^{\cdot^{\cdot^{e^{\Re\left(\frac{1}{n^s}\right)}}}}}}_m \text{ else } A(n,k)=0$$

where:
$$n=1..N$$
$$k=1..N$$.

This a matrix starting:

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 e^{e^{e^e}} & e^{e^{e^e}} & e^{e^{e^e}} & e^{e^{e^e}} & e^{e^{e^e}} & e^{e^{e^e}} & e^{e^{e^e}} & \dots\\
 e^{e^{e^{e^{2^{-s}}}}} & 0 & e^{e^{e^{e^{2^{-s}}}}} & 0 & e^{e^{e^{e^{2^{-s}}}}} & 0 & e^{e^{e^{e^{2^{-s}}}}} \\
 e^{e^{e^{e^{3^{-s}}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{3^{-s}}}}} & 0 & e^{e^{e^{e^{3^{-s}}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{3^{-s}}}}} & 0 & e^{e^{e^{e^{3^{-s}}}}} \\
 e^{e^{e^{e^{4^{-s}}}}} & 0 & e^{e^{e^{e^{4^{-s}}}}} & 0 & e^{e^{e^{e^{4^{-s}}}}} & 0 & e^{e^{e^{e^{4^{-s}}}}} \\
 e^{e^{e^{e^{5^{-s}}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{5^{-s}}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{5^{-s}}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{5^{-s}}}}} & 0 & e^{e^{e^{e^{5^{-s}}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{5^{-s}}}}} \\
 e^{e^{e^{e^{6^{-s}}}}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{e^{e^{e^{6^{-s}}}}} & 0 & e^{e^{e^{e^{6^{-s}}}}} \\
 e^{e^{e^{e^{7^{-s}}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{7^{-s}}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{7^{-s}}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{7^{-s}}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{7^{-s}}}}} & e^{e^{e^{e^{7^{-s}}}}} & 0 \\ \vdots & & & & & & & \ddots
\end{array}
\right)$$

Let $\lambda(n)$ be the sequence of **eigenvalues** of the matrix $A$.

> Show that $m$ pieces of natural logarithms of the eigenvalues $\lambda(n)$:
>
> $$\text{sgn}(\lambda(n))\underbrace{\log(\log(...\log(}_m |\lambda(n)|)...))=\Re\left(\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}\right)$$
>
> converge to the real part of the Möbius function divided by $n^s$ for
>   $s$ a complex number, as $m \rightarrow \infty$.

Mathematica program to demonstrate the conjecture:

```
(*start*)
Clear[A, s, mm, nn, i];
s = 1/2 + I;
mm = 7;
Do[A = Table[
   Table[If[GCD[n, k] == 1, Exp[Exp[Exp[Exp[Re[1/n^s]]]]], 0], {k, 1, 
     nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
 a = Eigenvalues[A];
 Print[b = 
   N[Table[Sign[a[[i]]] If[a[[i]] == 0, 0, 
       Log[Log[Log[Log[Abs[Re[a[[i]]]]]]]]], {i, 1, nn}], 6]], {nn, 1,
   mm}]
MatrixForm[A]
Total[b] - Sum[MoebiusMu[n]/n^s, {n, 1, Length[b]}]
(*end*)
```

The original program with a simpler claim:

```
(*start*)
Clear[A, s, mm, nn, i];
s = 1;
mm = 7;
Do[A = Table[
   Table[If[GCD[n, k] == 1, Exp[Exp[Exp[Exp[1/n^s]]]], 0], {k, 1, 
     nn}], {n, 1, nn}];
 a = Eigenvalues[A];
 Print[b = 
   N[Table[Sign[a[[i]]] If[a[[i]] == 0, 0, 
       Log[Log[Log[Log[Abs[a[[i]]]]]]]], {i, 1, nn}], 6]], {nn, 1, mm}]
MatrixForm[A]
Total[b] - Sum[MoebiusMu[n]/n^s, {n, 1, Length[b]}]
(*end*)
```

And its output:

{1.00000,-0.500000,-0.333333,-0.200000,0.166667,-0.142857,0}

This question has gone unanswered for a few years now, as part of an earlier question on Mathematics stack exchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156035/8530).

---

Edit 27.11.2019:

This is what I had in mind:

$$\text{Fourier Transform of } \Lambda(n) \sim \Re\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{n=\infty} \frac{1}{n} \zeta(1/2+i \cdot t)\sum\limits_{d|n}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(1/2+i \cdot t-1)}}\right)$$

Where the real part of the Möbius function divided by $d^s$ is part of the function. In other words, the **eigenvalues**, with the magnitudes logarithmized $m$ times, **accentuate** the Riemann zeta zeros when multiplied with the Riemann zeta function.

[image: spectrum accentuated by eigenvalues]

[More about the zeta zero spectrum](https://mathoverflow.net/q/162076/25104)

Comment: Is $m=4$?   $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$

Comment: In the program I used $m=4$ but $m \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: What is the size of $A$?

Comment: Sounds like it could be related to Redheffer matrix and it's variants. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redheffer_matrix

Comment: $$\Lambda(n)=\lim\limits_{s \rightarrow 1} \zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(s-1)}}$$

Comment: $$\varphi^{-1}(n) = \lim\limits_{s \rightarrow 1} \zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n} \mu(d)(e^{d})^{(s-1)}$$